# Design patterns: many objects of same type with multiple objects of other type

Tags: java, design-patterns

Which would be a good approach if I were to make an application where I had to store all countries in Europe and as well as their respective cities (for example)?

I considered using an enum to store the information but since that'd require me to hard-code lots of data I quickly scrapped that idea.

Afterwards I considered something like:

```
class Country {

    public Country(String name, City... cities) {
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

That way I'd be able to read cities from a .txt and create objects accordingly thus eliminating the need for manual labor. However, that brings a new issue, where do I store my list of countries? I considered the following:

```
class Country {

    public Country(String name, City... cities) {
        //Stuff
    }

    public static List<Country> getAllCountries() {
        return countries;
    }
}
```

but I feel like such code pollutes the structure and cleanliness of the project.

I thought about going with a combination of an enum (Country) and a class (City) but that doesn't feel right either.

Ideally I'd like to be able to access countries like an enum `Country.FRANCE` or `Country.getByName("France")` but neither seems like a solution here. So, I'm back to my initial question. What is a good way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The list of cities is big and it's quite possible that you'll need more than just a name for a country or a city. Storing this information in file for regular use is impractical and definitely enumerations are not for that. Instead, you could use a database, which you can populate with the Geonames data. The Geonames database contains the information about locations of cities and much more else. You can use ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 codes to identify countries and Geoname IDs to reference cities in the country. There are also localized names of the countries, if you want to present the list of countries in different languages.

This data can be downloaded from here (description is below):
http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

You can easily find the code for importing the files into your database of choice in Github - there are many examples for doing just that.

With the database your code could look like this:

```
class CountryRepository {
    public Country findByISOCode(String code) { ... }
    public List<Country> findAll() { 
       // JDBC or JPA query
    }
}

class SomeBusinessLogic {
    private CountryRepository countries;
    private CityRepository cities;
    ...
    Country france = countries.findByISOCode("FR");
    List<City> largestFrenchCities = cities.findTopLargestIn(france, 5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I should probably have clarified this in the OP but country/city is merely an example of the problem. Generally speaking I guess it's kind of like a x-to-many parent/child relationship? In your example, if you didn't query a database, how would you initialize the country list?

Comment: Without context your question becomes too abstract to answer. It always depends on the domain, which solution to choose. How many objects are there? Will they change during application lifetime? Are there any other relationships between these objects and other domain entities? What is the execution environment and what options do you have there?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashMap. This is a storage for a key and value pair.
It could look like this :

```
HashMap<Country, City> europe = new HashMap<Country, City>();
```